# 'attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0' ’after the power cut

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

My machine is Dell PowerEdge730, Ubuntu 20.04.

The power is out. I try to reboot it after power return.

The grub interface appears first. In the past, I always reboot the computer with these commands and work well.

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-41-generic ro root=/dev/sda3
initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
boot
```

But now after the execution of the second line of command, **attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'** appear.

I want to know how to reboot it correctly.

The commands I try to get the computer's information as the following images

[image: sammple image]

Comment: 5.11 is **not** a *supported* kernel of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, so either you've a ~year behind no upgrades & security fixes, or something is very wrong.  I'd suggest booting *live* media & perform checks firstly on your drive health, secondly on the file-system - if errors are detected & fixed with the *fs* I'd expect normal boot after that, but the 5.11 kernel shows a security concern if your machine is online.  Check what you're using (5.4 is the GA kernel of 20.04, 5.15 is the HWE kernel for 20.04)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What should I do when I booting by live media?What's the fs?I'm sorry about I don't know ubuntu very well.And I really haven't updated it for a long time.

Comment: *fs* is the file-system I referred to; ie. you should be checking drive health (*out of good habit on any issue such as you're reporting; hopefully you have the system perform daily checks anyway - but given you're a year+ behind on security fixes I suspect you're not*), then file-system checks.  If *fs* checks detect issues as I mentioned they'll be fixed & you'll be able to boot normally as I stated.  That machine should be kept offline given how far behind on security fixes it is.  (*other than commands I didn't mention; this is generic IT knowledge & not Ubuntu specific; NTFS is a fs*)